# How do I make something happen on the screen even without a key being pressed?

Tags: c++, game-physics, ncurses

I am making Pacman in C++ with the Ncurses library. I am able to move Pacman with my code, but I want to move it so that pacman keeps moving even when I am not pressing any key and when I press another direction key, it changes direction. Right now, the pacman only takes one step when I press a key. Also I have to press a key 2 or 3 times before pacman moves in that direction.

```
if (ch==KEY_LEFT)
{
    int b,row,column;
    getyx(stdscr,row,column);
    int h; 
    do    // do-whileloop to move the pacman left until it hits the wall
    {
        column-=1;
        mvprintw(row,column,">");  //print the ">" symbol
        refresh();
        waitf(0.1);      //this pauses the game for 0.1sec
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));      
        mvprintw(row,column,">");
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        refresh();
        waitf(0.1);
        mvprintw(row,(b),"O");  //showing the open mouth of pacman
        refresh();
        waitf(0.1);
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));a
        mvprintw(row,column,"O");
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        h = getch();
    }
    while(h == KEY_LEFT);
}

right = getch();
```

loop to move right in an if condition

```
up = getch();
```

loop to move up in an if condition

```
down = getch();
```

oop for moving down in an if condition.

Comment: Place such a condition that when user moves the pacman, it goes into a  loop and stops and waits for next instruction only when it reaches the wall.

Comment: but I want that whenever another key is pressed,pacman changes it's direction.

Answer (score 5):

The standard solution to this is the [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The character has six or so possible states: standing, moving up, moving right, moving down, moving left, dead. Rather than a keypress directly moving the character, the keypress should change the character's state.

In such a small application, rather than implementing an incredibly flexible finite-state machine, you may use a very simple implementation as such:

```
enum PlayerState {
    Standing,
    MovingUp,
    MovingRight,
    MovingDown,
    MovingLeft,
    Dead
};
```

Then, inside your game loop you can add a very simple state check which then takes the appropriate action for the frame.

```
switch(state) {
case Standing:
    break;
case MovingUp:
    player.PositionY += 1;
    break;
// ...
}
```

The last step is to hook input, which depends on your method of retrieving input. Using callbacks, an example is:

```
void KeyDown(Key k) {
    switch(k) {
    case UpArrow:
        if(state != Dead)
            state = MovingUp;
        break;
    case RightArrow:
        if(state != Dead)
            state = MovingRight;
    // ...
    }
}
```

You can see why in a larger project it would be important to implement a more flexible finite-state machine, but hopefully this example has given you an easy-to-understand idea.

Answer (score 3):

You need an equivalent of [`kbhit`](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html), ie. a non-blocking `getch`. Which really gives the solution, set [`O_NONBLOCK`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) on the input. See an example [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html). Once you have this, simply loop contiguously and just check for the key hit, w/o waiting on actual key press.

Comment: +1 for O_NONBLOCK, it's been a while since I've touched these C APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Function `getch` is blocked until some key is pressed. If you don't want to be blocked then call `_kbhit` before `getch` too make sure that there is something in input buffer.

EDIT: Take a look at ncurses functions `nodelay` and `cbreak`. They enable asynchronous input.

Comment: I am not able to use kbhit() with ncurses.

Comment: What OS you are on, and what compiler do you use?

Comment: g++ compiler.I am using putty software to connect with my university server.

Comment: You are using windows to connect via Putty, but the code is running on server, and the server is probably some kind of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model, it will help you with this problems and all the other problems that you will have if you continue your program like this.

Edit: shortcut

To move your pacman continuously you will need a separate thread to control it and make it move. Take a look at pthreads for that.

If you keep only the user input in the main run loop of your program, the problem that you have to press the keys a few times will go away too (the problem here is that the processor has to be on the getch() line when you press the key, otherwise it will not be detected.

Comment: This answer is too broad and it does not really answers the question.

Comment: I am a beginner and I am short of time.please can you tell me some other solution?

Comment: can you tell me of a simpler way?

Comment: you can increment the pacman position in you main run loop, but i don't think your professor will be happy with that solution

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy
for each direction make 4 function 
and inside the function,put in the other 3 direction function which get activated by kbhit.

and put a else statement in which it keeps moving forward if you do not  hit a button i.e (!kbhit());
and then put all this in a loop.

---

If you do this for all the direction functions you should be able to get the desirable outcome.

Comment: The other answers at least attempt to address the question and provide specific solutions. You, on the other hand, just pasted the same badly formatted code from your own (closed) questions with no explanation or guidance. Please look at other questions and answers on SO to get an idea of how the site works. Don't take this personally, I know you can do better. Cheers.

Comment: i dont know why every1 keeps saying its badly formated how can i make it better ???

Comment: The most obvious format issues are indenting and brackets. They appear in seemingly random places and are inconsistent throughout your code. The compiler doesn't care about formatting but it helps (or hurts) a human reader's ability to quickly understand the structure and control flow. Why do some of your functions appear before `main()` and other closely-related functions appear after? It looks like a random jumble with no planning or organization. You have single-character variables names that give no clue as to their purpose and declared variables that are never used.